# how to sort by colors in pandas dataframe or python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

need to find a way to sort the excel by colors. Tried pandas, can sort by values, but could not find a way to sort by colors. 
is there a library or method ready in python for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean group by color? if so just use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Sorting requires the scale to have lower/higher values. As far as I know color is even everywhere in its scale (i.e. its not clear if green is higher than blue or vice versa).

Comment: no, I am looking for a method that can automate the excel build in function of sort by colors (user can define which font color goes first and which goes 2nd in sequence...) in python

Comment: Show what have you done already and where in code is your issue so people can help you. @user9571515